# Matlab 3D matrix transform 3rd dimension by 2D matrix vectorization

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have 3D matrix `A` of size `N, M, 3` and 2D transformation `T` of size `3, 3` that I apply to the 3rd dimension of matrix `A`. In case it's relevant, this 3D matrix is an RGB image.

My current solution looks like this:

```
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:M
        A(i, j, :) = T * [A(i, j, r); A(i, j, g); A(i, j, b)];
    end
end
```

But I'm curious if there is a way to vectorize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. 
First switch the dimensions so the channel will be the first:

```
B = permute(A,[3,1,2])
```

Then reshape B to be a matrix of size 3xN*M:

```
C = reshape(B,3,[])
```

And now compute a matrix multiplication:

```
D = T*C;
```

You then need to reshape and permute back:

```
E = permute(reshape(D,3,M,N),[2,3,1])
```

I didn't test it so there may be something missing, but generally this should work (and fast!)

Comment: Very nice! I think you need to transpose `C`. This was my approach: `reshape((T*reshape(permute(A, [3 1 2]), 3, [])).', size(A))`

Comment: @LuisMendo It worked, thanks. And I got 100x speedup!